# How to get fortnox access token with the help of authorization code and client secret using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a sand box account in fortnox and i am trying to get the access token using following code, but i keep getting same error:

```
$requestMethod = "GET";

$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    'Authorization-Code: '. AUTHORIZATION_CODE .'',
    'Client-Secret: '. CLIENT_SECRET .'',
    'Content-Type: '. CONTENT_TYPE .'',
    'Accept: '. ACCEPTS .''
);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/xampp/htdocs/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.fortnox.se/3/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $options);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $requestMethod);

$curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

//echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds for url ' . $info['url'];

echo $curlResponse;

if ($curlResponse === FALSE) {

    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);

}
curl_close($ch);
```

Error: PHP / 4.5.37 Can not sign in , access tokens , or client- secret missing ( 2000311 ) .

Answer (score 1):

I get the `Access-Token` using the following code which is very close to your code. It worked fine for me.

Your error is described on the [Errors](http://developer.fortnox.se/documentation/general/errors/) page, but it adds nothing new to the text you already shown.

Please note that you can retrive the `Access-Token` only once, check [Authentication](http://developer.fortnox.se/documentation/general/authentication/) section in the Fortnox documentation.

> An Access-Token can only be retrieved once with every Authorization-Code, multiple requests with the same Authorization-Code will make both the Authorization-Code and the Access-Token invalid.

```
public function actionRetrieveAccessToken($authCode, $clientSecret)
{
    $headers = [
        'Authorization-Code: ' . $authCode,
        'Client-Secret: ' . $clientSecret,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.fortnox.se/3/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $responseText = curl_exec($curl);

    $response = json_decode($responseText, true);
    if (isset($response['ErrorInformation'])) {
        echo 'Request failed with error messages:' . PHP_EOL;
        echo $response['ErrorInformation']['Error'] . ': ';
        echo $response['ErrorInformation']['Message'];
        echo ' (' . $response['ErrorInformation']['Code'] . ')' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Access Token: ' . $response['Authorization']['AccessToken'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content_type = 'application/json';
$api_url="api url here";
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: '.$content_type.'',
        'Authorization : '.'Bearer ' . $this->access_token
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
if (!empty($data)) 
{
    $data = json_encode($data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}
$response = curl_exec($curl);
logthis($response,"utils");
curl_close($curl);
```